# How to run multiple instances of the same Meteor app in development?

Tags: meteor

I've tried to run my Meteor application within two individual consoles at the same time like this:

**cli #1**

`D:\Some\Project> meteor`

**cli #2**

`D:\Some\Project> meteor --port 4000`

If I try to run two instances of the same application at the same time, I get this **output from my 2nd instance**:

```
=> Started proxy.

Error: EBUSY, rmdir 'D:\Some\Project\.meteor\local\build\programs\server'
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to mitigate this error, so that I can check some of my cross-instance functionality?

I do realize that I could copy the entire project folder, and run them with the same MONGO_URL, but a better approach would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 6):

Start the first instance of your app:

`meteor`

This command will start your app and MongoDD instance running on port 3001 with `meteor` database.

Wait until your first instance starts, then open up the second console and type:

`export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor && meteor --port 4000`